# convert characters to month and year ( date ) in R

Tags: r

How do I convert a string "Apr-16" to `Month` April of 2016 ?

I tired `as.Date(x, format ..)` , that isn't helping .

What options do I have here ?

Comment: Which data type do you expect as result? There is no native date-alike data type in base R that represents only the month and the year. The answer depends on what you want to do with the parsed result (date calculations or just printing it as string?)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- "Apr-16"
x <- as.Date(paste0("1-",x),format="%d-%b-%y")
format(x,"%B of %Y")
[1] "April of 2016"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `regex`

```
sub("-", "il of 20", x)
#[1] "April of 2016"
```

---

Or using `yearmon` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
format(as.Date(as.yearmon(x, "%b-%y")), "%B of %Y")
#[1] "April of 2016"
```

#### data

```
x <- "Apr-16"
```